# A search box in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, search-box

I have this search box :

[image]

And the code of the search box is :

```
<form method = "post" action="search.php" class = "pull-down  navbar-search">
    <div class="input-append">
        <input class="search-query input-medium"  name="search_query" type="text" placeholder="Arama Yap" >
        <button type = "submit "class="btn btn-large" type="button"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want the search box to have no space between the box and the button. How can I accomplish it? Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Scroll down on this link to the bit that says "Search Form";

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

Here's a fiddle showing it working: http://jsfiddle.net/3PgU2/

```html
<form class="form-search">
    <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" class="span2 search-query">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
    </div>
    <div class="input-prepend">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
        <input type="text" class="span2 search-query">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I have read that link and the made the changes but nothing changed visually. Here is the current form of the code :    `<form method = "post" action="search.php" class = "form-search">
      <div class="input-append">
      <input class="search-query span2"  name="search_query" type="text" placeholder="Arama Yap" >
       <button type = "submit "class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
      </form>`

Comment: I've added a fiddle with a working demo in my answer. Just copy that and you should be good to go.

Comment: The difference is in the classes - form-search which you are using currently, and navbar-search which u were using previously